# Binding DataReader to ASP.NET Repeater

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I've spent too long on this now, and I'm pretty sure I'm fairly close to the solution but I just need a "little push" over the edge.

I want to grab all fields from my table 'FamousQuotes' and repeat them in a repeater. Unfortunately at the minute, this isn't working; I don't get any compile-time errors, but neither do I see any data appear at runtime in my repeater

Here is my code behind:

```
Sub randomQuote()
        Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("BookMeetConnString").ConnectionString)
        conn.Open()
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [FamousQuotes] ORDER BY rnd(INT(NOW*id)-NOW*id)", conn)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Dim datareader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        If datareader.HasRows Then
            datareader.Read()
            quoteCascade.DataSource = datareader
            quoteCascade.DataBind()
            datareader.Close()
            datareader = Nothing
        End If

        conn.Close()
    End Sub
```

You don't probably don't need to see my repeater code, it's nothing remarkable, but here you go:

```
 <asp:Repeater id="quoteCascade" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <blockquote>
        "<%#Container.DataItem("Quote")%>"
    <small>
        <%#Container.DataItem("SourceName")%><cite title="Source Title">
            <%#Container.DataItem("SourceTitle")%></cite></small>
    </blockquote>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

So what's going wrong here?

EDIT: I've updated my question with **working code**, a la Damien Joe's answer below:

```
Sub randomQuote()
    Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("BookMeetConnString").ConnectionString)
    conn.Open()
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT TOP 6 * FROM [FamousQuotes] ORDER BY rnd(INT(NOW*id)-NOW*id)", conn)
    quoteCascade.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    quoteCascade.DataBind()
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() is not necessary as you are already executing the reader later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just execute datareader on the fly, no need to call ExecuteNonQuery()

```
        quoteCascade.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        quoteCascade.DataBind();            
        //Close your connection
```